# no such table: Schedule_playerweightlifting

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='PlayerWeightLifting',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ('time', models.IntegerField(default=-1)),
        ('medal', models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('GOLD', 'GOLD'), ('SILVER', 'SILVER'), ('BRONZE', 'BRONZE'), ('FOURTH', 'FOURTH')], max_length=256)),
        ('player', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='Schedule.Player')),
    ],
    options={
        'ordering': ['time'],
    },
),
```

This is my model *PlayerWeightLifting* from 0001_initial.py file. But when i am running it, it is showing "no such table: Schedule_playerweightlifting", Below is my corresponding model:

```
class PlayerWeightLifting(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weightlifting = models.ForeignKey(WeightLifting, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    time = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    medal = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True, choices=MEDAL_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.weightlifting) + str(" ") + str(self.player)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['time']
```

I have an another similar type of model class, which is working fine, i am stuck in this database thing. Help me!

This is the portion from admin.py :

```
admin.site.register(PlayerWeightLifting)
```

There is no type of error showing on terminal while running *python manage.py makemigrations* and *python manage.py migrate* command, but when i am opening admin, it is just showing, no such table, what can be the probable causes? I even tried **Python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb** Any help will be appreciated!Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the complete error & also your admin.py file?

Comment: Hey @anshumananand , i just rechecked, admin.py is fine, i have imported the class on top and written the register code as well, when i am opening my admin website, there is column of PlayerWeightLifting, but on opening, it is showing no such table ERROR.

Comment: ok let me run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Admin Screenshot]

Aadil, i used your code and it seem there are no problem with it at my end.

I think youre creating those models using `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py` from  your DB.
Sometimes the datatypes get tangled up bit and we don't get what we want like in your `Date` model there should have `DateField` or `DateTimeField` also `default` should be 
as mentioned in code below or `NONE`.

BTW my `Models.py` was:

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    pass
class WeightLifting(models.Model):
    pass

class PlayerWeightLifting(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weightlifting = models.ForeignKey(WeightLifting, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
    time = models.IntegerField(default='')
    medal = models.CharField(max_length=256,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.weightlifting) + str(" ") + str(self.player)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['time']
```

If the problem persists try to create models first and then make your db by migration. See if that works.

Comment: When i am changing some field in that particular model, and doing makemigrations, it is detecting that change, but at the end after migrating , it is showing no such table, the class is stuck in middle i guess. Your answer is not helping my issue.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the screenshot, i can understand, it should work , like it worked for you. But bad luck for me :(

Comment: Are using dbSqlite? if Yes, delete this db & run `python makemigrations appname` then `migrate`. See what happens.

Comment: I am not able to figure out my issue, where i am doing it wrong. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: I have many saved things, its a little big project, deleting that folder will delete all my saved thing,right? @anshuman anand

Comment: Yeah, i understand but you can try one more thing. Reverse all the migrations using `python manage.py migrate my_app zero` and Re-run all your migrations.

Comment: This method is also not working, somehow model has created but it is not detected by sqlite, thats the whole issue : (

Comment: Deleting dbSqlite and migrating again worked for me. Thanks @anshuman anand!

Comment: @AadilHoda Welcome Sir, Happy to help.